# Is there a way to quantify the entanglement in a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, hydrogen

It is known that whenever the Hamiltonian contains an interaction part, the two interacting subsystems are entangled, thus an electron is surely entangled to a proton in a hydrogen atom. The discrepancy in mass of the two particles leads to a rather small entanglement, but it seems that no one has given a quantitative measure for it. [[1]](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.18977) provides analysis on the reduced density function of the system, but gives no quantification; [[2]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437104010635?via%3Dihub) measures entanglement in hyperfine interaction and the thermal entanglement with concurrence, but the entanglement in orbital motion is not defined. I have seen such entanglement quantified with von Neumann entropy for the internal motion of helium, where the atom is partitioned into two interacting electron-proton subsystems. So, is there a way to regard the electron and the proton as individual subsystems and quantify their orbital entanglement with one another?

Comment: You say 'no one has calculated this' like it would make a huge difference to the state of physics research if they did. It's a valid question, but if it's not in the published literature it's because it's ultimately of limited interest.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I know it's probably of limited utility value, as I've stated that the large difference in mass leads to small entanglement. I'm only curious, since by knowing, my sphere of knowledge would be a little bit more complete.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I strongly disagree that "*if it's not in the published literature it's because it's ultimately of limited interest*", else the literature would simply just stop dead and accept nothing else, as everything new would just be "uninteresting".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been calculated, but only very recently. And yes, it is of high intrinsic value for science, specially with the rise of quantum computing.

The article [Hydrogenic entanglement](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aba30f/meta) builds on the entropy measure from your reference [1] to calculate an explicit principal quantum number-dependent entanglement formula for the free hydrogenic system (eq. 35).

Then they calculate entanglement for a localised hydrogenic system, assuming that lab-trapped hydrogen can be modeled after a three-dimensional Gaussian wavepacket, but entanglement is more difficult to calculate, so they use the information contained in the second statistical moments of the localised hydrogenic state (eq. 52), which now depends on all $n$, $l$, and $m$ spatial quantum numbers.

Comment: Why is the entanglement between the electron and proton in a hydrogen atom relevant to quantum computing?

Comment: Inderectly, perhaps. While entanglement is not a *sine qua non* concept for quantum computing, it might have applications such as in superdense coding and cluster states. Now, as candidate materials for storing qubits are invetigated, IMO its important to understand how these materials present entanglement, and while the H atom itself is not a direct candidate, it may help understand entanglement in compound materials. Also, for the general understanding of entanglement, and the techniques used, for instance, to measure entropy of entangled systems.